# "A presidente" ou "A presidenta"?

Tags: ortografia, uso-de-palavras, diferenças-transatlânticas, localização

Notei que alguns tem usado *"presidenta"*, mas penso eu que a palavra presidente seja usada para ambos gêneros, ou estou enganado?

Penso isto, pois é semelhante a palavra *"regente"*, *"estudante"* e *motorista*, que me parecem ser situações semelhantes (claro que cada palavra pode ter sua regra/contra-regra), ou seja são palavras que são usadas tanto no masculino quanto no feminino.

É correto utilizar a palavras *"presidenta"*, já é aceito por outros países e localizações que falam português além do Brasil?

Comment: Mais um recurso interessante: http://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica.aspx?DID=4872

Comment: Quero deixar claro para quem negativou que a pergunta aqui não tem motivação politica, por falar nisso houve uma resposta aqui que essa sim tinha motivação ou orientação politica que inclusive já foi removida. O intuito aqui é meramente o  entendimento "técnico" do idioma e como ele evoluiu ou vai evoluir.

Comment: Você usa a palavra 'pacienta'?

Comment: @fhcimolin isso não tem nada haver com "cargo" ou neologismo, e eu não tenho orientação politica em favor de algo ou de alguma "pauta". "Paciente" não é um "cargo", até entendo o seu comparativo, seria como "estudante" e "estudanta", mas aqui o objetivo não é apoiar ou criticar politicos ou politicagens, é só sobre português. Recomendo ler https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 24):

Em português europeu/de Portugal, a palavra "presidenta" só é utilizada de forma popular ou pejorativa (ver [aqui](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa-aao/presidenta)):

> pre.si.den.ta [prəziˈdẽtɐ]
>   **nome feminino**
>   1.  *popular* mulher que preside
>   2.  *popular, pejorativo* esposa do presidente

Isto deve-se ao facto de "presidente" ter dois géneros e se referir à *pessoa* que preside, e não ao *homem* que preside (ver [aqui](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa-aao/presidente)):

> pre.si.den.te [prəziˈdẽt(ə)]
>   **nome de 2 géneros**
>   1.  pessoa que preside
>   2.  chefe de uma assembleia, tribunal, junta, etc.
>   3.  título do chefe de Estado em algumas repúblicas
>
> **adjectivo de 2 géneros**
>   que preside; que dirige

Comment: Foi o que eu disse na pergunta sobre presidir :) ... Então pode ser correto no Brasil, mas não em outros locais que usam o idioma? No mesmo sentido que motorista é usado para homem e mulher. Ótima resposta.

Comment: Acho que não se pode dizer que é "incorrecto" em Portugal. Mas só se usa popularmente, e _pela minha experiência_ não é comum nem popularmente.

Comment: Até aqui me parece que a sua resposta é a correta, e que a minha resposta complementa a sua.

Comment: Ou seja, se uma mulher que está na presidência e exige que a tratem como presidenta, está sendo "ignorante" e sexista?

Comment: @bigown Uh...não. Primeiro porque a língua está em constante mudança, e podem surgir novas palavras, regras gramaticais e ortografias ao longo do tempo. Segundo porque a língua _é_ cultura, evoluindo portanto a par desta: ["As línguas estão aí para mostrar a realidade e não para a esconder de acordo com a ideologia dominante (...)"](http://www.dn.pt/arquivo/2008/interior/presidenta-porque-sou-mulher-994586.html) — se surge algo cuja existência antes era impedida por normas ou preconceitos sociais, pode também surgir uma nova palavra que serve para designar essa mesma coisa.

Comment: (cont.) Faz mais sentido reconhecer que existe um problema social para resolver, e usar a língua como instrumento para resolvê-lo, do que tentarmos agarrar-nos às falhas do nosso meio de expressão de modo a perpetuar esses mesmos problemas sociais.

Comment: Mesmo impostas por uma pessoa?

Comment: @bigown [Não parece ser esse o caso, pois não?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/307/15)

Comment: http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/320/23

Comment: @bigown apesar da minha resposta parecer apoiar o termo, ainda sim coloquei ela mais como "informação" do que uma resposta conclusiva. O melhor exemplo que vi aqui foram os casos de `estudante` e `regente` (maestro ou governo), não faria muito sentido dizer que são palavras masculinas, assim como presidente. Mas de todo modo se for algo que se tornar popular então tudo bem, é a evolução da língua, mas realmente imposta por uma pessoa não me parece um caminho "certo".

Answer (score 21):

A lei federal 2.749, de 1956, do senador *Mozart Lago* (1889-1974), determina o uso oficial da forma feminina para designar cargos públicos ocupados por mulheres. Era letra morta, até o país escolher sua primeira mulher à Presidência da República.

É também interessante notar a existência de "presidenta", desde 1899, pelo dicionário de *Cândido de Figueiredo*:

> Presidenta, f. (neol.) mulher que preside; mulher de um presidente. (Fem. de presidente.)

Fonte:

- http://exame.abril.com.br/carreira/noticias/presidente-ou-presidenta-qual-o-certo
- http://revistalingua.com.br/textos/62/presidente-ou-presidenta-248988-1.asp

Comment: Mas a forma feminina de presidente, pelo menos em Portugal, é presidente... esta resposta é útil, mas não me parece responder à pergunta.

Comment: @ANeves foi por este motivo que não selecionei resposta correta, pois nenhuma é completa, tanto que comentei na resposta do JNat: [*Até aqui me parece que a sua resposta é a correta, e que a minha resposta complementa a sua.*](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/30/a-presidente-ou-a-presidenta/#comment479_312)

Comment: Vale notar que no dicionário Cândido de Figueiredo, *presidenta* está classificado como um neologismo.

Comment: @falsarella sim (neol.)

Answer (score 19):

#### Conclusão <sup>([TL; DR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn%27t_read))</sup>

Aparentemente, existiu algum uso da palavra *presidenta* no passado, e agora voltou a ocorrer devido a acontecimentos políticos. Nitidamente, o sufixo é independentemente de gênero, sendo que quem define o gênero é o artigo que o acompanha; por isso eu, particularmente, não vejo necessidade de se permitir o uso correto da escrita *presidenta*. Mas, no final das contas, o importante é que o significado seja passado corretamente, independentemente da forma.

---

A seguir estão disponíveis os resultados detalhados da pesquisa exploratória que realizei para utilizar como referência e insumo nesta análise.

---

#### [presidente - Wikicionário](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/presidente):

> #### Substantivo
>
> **pre.si.*den*.te**, *[comum aos dois gêneros](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comum_de_dois_g%C3%AAneros)*
>
> <sub>Obs.: Também ocorre o feminino presidenta. <sup>[1] [2]</sup></sub>
>
> 1. Chefe de uma nação
> 2. Pessoa que dirige os trabalhos duma entidade deliberativa
> 3. cargo mais alto de uma empresa
>
> [...]
>
> #### Referências
>
> 1. Academia Brasileira de Letras. *Vocabulário Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa*: [presidenta](http://www.academia.org.br/abl/cgi/cgilua.exe/sys/start.htm?sid=23)
> 2. [Houaiss, Antônio](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant%C3%B4nio_Houaiss); Villar, Mauro de Salles. “presidente”. *[Dicionário Houaiss da Língua Portuguesa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicion%C3%A1rio_Houaiss_da_L%C3%ADngua_Portuguesa)*. Rio de Janeiro: [Objetiva](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objetiva_(editora)), 2001. [ISBN 85-7302-383-X](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/Especial:Fontes_de_livros/857302383X)

---

#### [Comum de dois gêneros - Wikipédia, a enciclopédia livre](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comum_de_dois_g%C3%AAneros):

> #### Comum de dois gêneros
>
> Em gramática, o **comum de dois gêneros** é a classificação que
> recebem os substantivos cujas formas masculina e feminina são
> idênticas mas são diferenciáveis pela presença de um modificante, tal
> como um artigo ou adjetivo.
>
> #### Exemplos
>
> - [...]
> - O presidente - A presidente.
> - [...]

---

#### [-nte - Wikicionário](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/-nte):

> #### Sufixo
>
> **-nte**
>
> 1. sufixo formador de adjetivos e substantivos

---

#### [A presidente ou a presidenta? - Professor Pasquale](https://www.facebook.com/507825759243026/photos/a.514476465244622.134034.507825759243026/876406239051641/):

> Que têm em comum palavras como “pedinte”, “agente”, “fluente”,
> “gerente”, “caminhante”, “dirigente” etc.? Não é difícil, é? O ponto
> em comum é a terminação “-nte”, de origem latina. Essa terminação
> ocorre no particípio presente de verbos portugueses, italianos,
> espanhóis…
>
> Termos como “presidente”, “dirigente”, “gerente”, entre
> inúmeros outros, são iguaizinhos nas três línguas, que, é sempre bom
> lembrar, nasceram do mesmo ventre. E que noção indica a terminação
> “-nte”? A de “agente”: gerente é quem gere, presidente é quem preside,
> dirigente é quem dirige e assim por diante.
>
> Normalmente essas palavras
> têm forma fixa, isto é, são iguais para o masculino e para o feminino;
> o que muda é o artigo (o/a gerente, o/a dirigente, o/a pagante, o/a
> pedinte).
>
> Em alguns (raros) casos, o uso fixa como alternativas as
> formas exclusivamente femininas, em que o “e” final dá lugar a um “a”.
> Um desses casos é o de “parenta”, forma exclusivamente feminina e não
> obrigatória (pode-se dizer “minha parente” ou “minha parenta”, por
> exemplo). Outro desses casos é justamente o de “presidenta”: pode-se
> dizer “a presidente” ou “a presidenta”.
>
> A esta altura alguém talvez já
> esteja dizendo que, por ser a primeira presidente/a do Brasil, Dilma
> Rousseff tem o direito de escolher. Sem dúvida nenhuma, ela tem esse e
> outros direitos. Se ela disser que quer ser chamada de “presidenta”,
> que seja feita a sua vontade -por que não?

---

#### [Presidente ou presidenta? - Francisco Leite Monteiro](http://dnoticias.pt/impressa/diario/cartasdoleitor/diario-12032009/87611-presidente-ou-presidenta):

> Responder 'sim e não' à pergunta se a palavra 'PRESIDENTE' tem género
> feminino [Revista 'MAIS' distribuída com o Diário de 8 de Março, pag.
> 14] justifica que, sobre a mesma, se acrescente um pouco mais.
>
> Do
> tempo em que eu andava na escola e, ainda que leigo na matéria, guardo
> em memória 'coisas' de que hoje pouco se cuida, não sendo estranho o
> facto de ter sido eliminado o latim que nesse tempo era uma disciplina
> obrigatória e que bem útil era para melhor se entender a evolução da
> língua de todos nós.
>
> Ora 'PRESIDENTE', o que não tem muito que saber,
> foi importado directamente do latim 'praesidente' - pessoa a quem cabe
> uma chefia, ou seja, presidir, do latim 'praesidere'. Quer como
> adjectivo quer como substantivo, em qualquer dos casos, é como se
> designa 'comum de dois géneros', o que é corrente na formação de
> palavras pela junção do sufixo 'nte' que, pode dizer-se, traduz a
> ideia do agente. No caso presente, a partir de 'presidir' o agente é
> pois o ou a Presidente. Analogamente, só para citar alguns: -
> comandante, gerente, amante, estudante, mantêm a uniformidade para
> masculino e feminino.
>
> Curiosamente, vai fazer um ano escrevi,
> comentando uma entrevista de Pilar del Rio, a jornalista espanhola
> casada com José Saramago, a um diário da capital, quando ela se
> insurgiu, arrogantemente, contra o entrevistador, classificando-o de
> ignorante, por se referir a ela como Presidente e não Presidenta da
> Fundação Saramago. Tratou-se de uma excentricidade que revela alguma
> ignorância, o que se percebe e se lhe desculpa, por não saber que além
> do mais, na língua portuguesa, os substantivos terminados em 'e', como
> é o caso, são geralmente uniformes, conservando uma unidade formal
> para os dois géneros.
>
> Em conclusão, eu respondo 'NÃO' à pergunta -
> 'PRESIDENTE' continua a ser um substantivo comum de dois géneros.

---

#### [PresidentA - a questão da flexão de gênero em palavras que denotam cargos de prestígio [documento]](http://www.academia.edu/11771476/PresidentA)

Este é um trabalho realizado por Danielle Takase Queiroz, Mitchell Tranjan e Raphaela Piorino para a disciplina de Morfologia do Português, da Profa. Dra. Marilza de Oliveira, da Universidade de São Paulo.

Vale a pena a leitura para uma perspectiva ampla quanto à flexão ao gênero feminino na política!

---

#### [Presidente ou Presidenta? - Programa do Jô [vídeo]](http://globotv.globo.com/rede-globo/programa-do-jo/v/presidente-ou-presidenta/2711852/):

Este é um vídeo que, apesar do teor humorístico, mostra de forma definitiva e clara o como e porquê desta questão. Eu, particularmente, concordo com a explicação da professora!

Vale a pena assistir. Além de aprender sobre a origem do sufixo, o desfecho é fantástico!

Comment: Sua explicação do `-nte` (assim como a palavra regente que é bem semelhante a presidente no uso) é ótima.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Obrigado pelo comentário! Eu realmente senti falta de mencionarem o sufixo nas outras respostas, o que me motivou a responder com uma pesquisa mais abrangente e de forma mais explicativa. Valeu!

Comment: A resposta precisa de um pequeno sumário no topo. Eu sugiro pôr a conclusão no topo, sem cabeçalho, seguida das diversas visões e justificações como estão.

Comment: O texto lido pelo Jô Soares é atribuído à uma pessoa que na verdade não o escreveu. [Aqui](http://noblat.oglobo.globo.com/noticias/noticia/2011/01/esclarecimento-359182.html) está uma resposta da professora Miriam Rita Moro Mine sobre isso (suponho que a resposta seja realmente dela). Esse tipo de recurso é muito usado para dar credibilidade a um texto. Em outras palavras, "se quiser que acreditem em você, diga que foi Einstein que disse".

Answer (score 6):

Já havia visto esta pergunta há tempos e não vejo como explicá-la melhor do que [este artigo do Profº Cláudio Moreno](http://sualingua.com.br/2010/11/08/presidente-ou-presidenta/).

Um argumento bastante interessante que ele apresenta é sobre a palavra 'primeira-ministra', que também teve seus momentos de estranheza:

> É muito importante lembrar o que ocorreu com o vocábulo
>   **primeiro-ministro**, que passou por várias etapas antes de conquistar
>   definitivamente o direito a ser usado no feminino. Quando o mundo
>   começou a falar em Indira Gandhi, eleita em 1966, a imprensa
>   brasileira foi apanhada de surpresa e saudou-a inicialmente como “**o
>   primeiro-ministro Indira**“. O absurdo da situação levou alguns a
>   ousarem uma combinação híbrida, cruza de jacaré com cobra-d’água: “**a
>   primeiro-ministro Indira**“. Esta forma esquisita foi a gota derradeira,
>   o passo decisivo para a metamorfose final, pois a não-concordância do
>   artigo com o substantivo, escandalosa demais para ser aceita por
>   qualquer ouvido normal, forçou a flexão natural para “**a
>   primeira-ministra Indira**“. Quando Golda Meir e Margaret Thatcher
>   apareceram no cenário mundial, o nosso léxico já tinha absorvido
>   plenamente a inovação. E presidente, como fica?

E como qualquer vocábulo, a sua aceitação/incorporação depende nós mesmos lusofalantes:

> Os usuários (nós, nossos filhos, nossos netos) vão se dividir entre
>   essas duas vertentes; com o passar das décadas, uma delas pode,
>   talvez, sufocar a outra, enviando-a para o porão das formas
>   aposentadas — ou, como acontece em dezenas de outros casos, as duas
>   conviverão lado a lado, deixando o falante livre para escolher.
>   Parafraseando meu mestre Luft, **eu não gosto de presidenta e não vou
>   adotá-lo — mas, e os outros com isso?**

Comment: Conheces a argumentação a favor de _primeiro-ministro Indira_? Em Portugal, ainda em 1979 alguns jornais escreveram _Senhora Primeiro Ministro_ (tivemos uma nesse ano), como se _primeiro-ministro_ fosse um substantivo como _dicionário_ (se o Houaiss tivesse sido mulher, ter-lhe-iam chamado _Senhora Dicionário_). Mas a comparação com _presidente/a_ não vai muito longe. _Senhora primeira-ministra_ impôs-se porque qualquer alternativa soava discordante, ao passo que não há nada de errado com _senhora presidente_.

Comment: Engraçado alguém não adotar presidenta, mas adotar usuário, é um bocadinho contra senso.

Answer (score 0):

Presidenta existe e consta no VOLPE. É perfeita no espanhol (presidenta Kirchner). No âmbito do português brasileiro havia caído em desuso. 
A palavra foi, porém, ressuscitada por certos grupos alinhados à ex-presidente Dilma Rousseff. 
É uma palavra que machuca o ouvido. Isso não é apenas minha opinião. A maior parte da imprensa não a incorporou. Outrossim, as pessoas comuns não a utilizam. Nunca ouvi alguém falar, v. g., que Fulana é presidenta do Supremo Tribunal ou que Cicrana é presidenta do Conselho da Petrobras. O uso se restringe à Sra. Dilma Rousseff mesmo.