# Quão prevalente é a linguagem neutra?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gênero

Eu assisti este vídeo do G1:

[Migues, vamos entender o que é gênero neutro | G1 EXPLICA | G1](https://youtu.be/u_8Cn_42BXs)

E fiquei curioso. Eu já tinha ouvido falar de linguagem neutra antes; cheguei a encontrar este wiki com uma página a respeito.

[Wiki Identidades: Linguagem não-binária ou neutra](https://identidades.wikia.org/pt-br/wiki/Linguagem_n%C3%A3o-bin%C3%A1ria_ou_neutra)

E tenho ouvido falar que isso é muito discutido nas redes sociais, inclusive com muita gente resistindo ao uso da linguagem neutra, seja por considerá-la "não-gramatical", "impronunciável", ou por não acreditar que *existam* pessoas trans ou com gênero não-binário.

Pessoalmente, acho que a polêmica sobre linguagem neutra é muito maior do que o seu uso efetivo, mas não tenho dados para confirmar ou descartar essa hipótese. Por isso, pergunto:

- Qual percentual da população brasileira usa linguagem neutra? Se sim, que percentual é esse, e quais variações são mais comuns?
- Que percentuais da população brasileira tem gênero não-binário, neutro, ou são transgênero?
- Há uma grande interseção entre as fatias de população acima?

Há pesquisa acadêmica séria sobre esses assuntos? Links para os artigos são bem-vindos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A polêmica em torno da linguagem neutra é muito mais político-social que linguística. O cerne da questão nesse momento não é a gramática ou o vocabulário, mas sim se a sociedade deveria ou não ser inclusiva e tolerante, e como atingir esse objetivo.

Infelizmente, o aspecto linguístico é frequentemente exagerado, quer por desinformação, quer por desonestidade daqueles que o instrumentalizam para defender sua posição política — como ocorreu com a resistência ao uso (correto) da palavra "presidenta" para se referir à primeira presidente mulher do Brasil, Dilma Rousseff.

Nesse sentido talvez essa pergunta erre um pouco o foco — afinal, o tamanho da minoria não deveria determinar o respeito que ela recebe: citar que os portadores da síndrome de Down são apenas 0,1% da população não é um argumento a favor ou contra a chamá-los de [mongoloides](https://dicionario.priberam.org/mongoloide). Vale também notar que a [postura oficial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336368/369732) do Stack Exchange é favor do uso de linguagem neutra, como parte de sua política de polidez.

Mas, claro, uma vez decidido que o caminho para a tolerância inclui a linguagem, uma discussão que se deve ter, e mais on-topic nesse site, é aquela sobre quais inovações seriam necessárias e efetivas. Um exemplo desse tipo de análise é a [tese](http://eprints.nottingham.ac.uk/60330/) "Para todes: gender-neutrality in the Portuguese language" (2020), de Auxland, Morrigan (University of Nottingham), que cita um exemplo de sucesso vindo da Suécia, que artificialmente introduziu um pronome neutro na língua, o "[hen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hen_(pronoun))" (em alternativa ao "hon" ("ela") e "han" ("ele")). Depois de enfrentar uma resistência inicial, ele foi [rapidamente adotado](https://www.businessinsider.com/sweden-has-non-gendered-pronoun-changing-the-way-people-think-2019-8) pela maioria da população e, de acordo com [um artigo de 2019](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.1908156116), sua adoção teve uma influência positiva mensurável.

Às questões.

> Qual percentual da população brasileira usa linguagem neutra? Se sim, que percentual é esse, e quais variações são mais comuns?

Uma análise bastante preliminar da frequência das palavas amigo/amiga e suas variações neutras no Twitter [indicaria](https://doi.org/10.25189/rabralin.v19i1.1709) que as versões neutras aparecem em menos de 3% dos *tweets* com alguma dessas palavras — como o não uso não indica a rejeição do termo, esses 3% são uma estimativa do número mínimo de *tweets* e, supostamente, dos usuários de linguagem neutra.
Nesse mesmo conjunto de dados, bastante limitado, "amigue" era cerca de 5 vezes mais frequente que "amigx".

> Que percentuais da população brasileira tem gênero não-binário, neutro, ou são transgênero?

Dados nesse sentido só agora começam a ser coletados, e revelam que seriam 2% da população. Provavelmente os mais confiáveis disponíveis vem de um [artigo](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-021-81411-4) de janeiro de 2021, que confirmam o valor de 2% e coincidem com a estimativa da Associação Nacional de Travestis e Transexuais.

Vale lembrar, contudo, que esses dados, especialmente por se basearem em autodeclarações, são fortemente influenciados pelo contexto social de intolerância e violência que essa fatia da população enfrenta, e é de esperar que esses números poderiam ser maiores noutro cenário.

> Há uma grande interseção entre as fatias de população acima?

Eu diria que certamente há, mas não encontro dados a respeito.

Comment: +1 pelos quatro primeiros parágrafos.

Comment: O uso de _presidenta_ é curioso, porque é uma preferência no sentido inverso: é preferir uma versão variável em género de _presidente_.

Comment: @Artefacto Pois é, pessoalmente prefiro usar "a presidente", mas vale notar que é uma "inovação" de [mais de 100 anos](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/307/2764).

Comment: @stafusa certo, eu alterei o comentário porque antecipei que esse reparo estivesse para vir, mas já não foi a tempo :p

Comment: @Artefacto Hehehe... de qualquer forma era um reparo menor. O que você comenta é muito relevante para a discussão, porque dá um exemplo de quão complicada ela é, mesmo com a melhor das boas intenções.

Comment: É bom saber que a polêmica é mais social do que gramatical. Eu venho considerando usar linguagem neutra faz algum tempo (como se referir a "irmãos" e "irmãs" numa palavra só, por exemplo?), mas queria ter evidência de se ela iria ou não "pegar", dada a polêmica a respeito.

Comment: Sua resposta me dá evidência suficiente: prevalência de linguagem neutra de pelo menos 3%, mais uma população de tamanho similar que precisa dela, mais pressão social em favor. Então, prevejo... [traz bola de cristal para si] que a linguagem neutra será amplamente adotada no Brasil em até 15 anos. 

Até lá, ela já terá alcançado os dicionários e gramáticas, e eu, dinossauro que sou, vou poder usá-la sem culpa de me sentir "errado".

Segure aí, melhor resposta! [lança a bola de cristal para @stafusa]

Comment: @jose_castro_arnaud Pessoalmente, tenho optado por adotar a linguagem neutra quando mais necessário ou simples, por exemplo, quando se trata de alguém de gênero desconhecido ou que explicitamente pediu um pronome neutro posso usar um "they" ou "a pessoa". Mas, pelo menos até agora, acabo quase nunca usando um "amigue".

Answer (score 1):

## Disclaimer

Isso daqui seria um comentário na resposta do outro stafusa (ele é meu primo), mas ficou grande e achei que merece se tornar uma resposta completa.

Além disso, deixo claro que sou um falante nativo da língua portuguesa e que vivo no Brasil desde que nasci.

## Percentual de pessoas não-binárias

Vamos começar com essa:

> Que percentuais da população brasileira tem gênero não-binário, neutro, ou são transgênero?

Não se sabe ao certo, pois há poucos levantamentos sobre isso. O governo brasileiro tentou fazer [um levantamento com base na população prisional em 2020](https://www.gov.br/mdh/pt-br/assuntos/noticias/2020-2/fevereiro/TratamentopenaldepessoasLGBT.pdf):

> Infelizmente, devido a natureza dos dados e a dificuldade de garantir a homogeneidade da amostra e a padronização do procedimento de coleta de dados, os dados quantitativos de pessoas LGBT nas prisões do Brasil não pode ser utilizado como instrumento de censo. Não há como garantir que todas as pessoas LGBT nas unidades prisionais respondentes foram efetivamente consultadas. Tampouco é possível dizer que os LGBT que, de fato, foram consultados, gozavam de ampla liberdade para declarar sua sexualidade e sua identidade de gênero sem risco de sanções tanto administrativas, quanto por parte dos outros internos.

Segundo [esta reportagem](https://exame.com/brasil/pesquisa-inedita-mapeia-populacao-lgbt-e-trans-nos-presidios-paulistas/), 2,44% da população prisional no Estado de São Paulo no início do ano de 2020 é/era LGBT, totalizando 5680 pessoas. Dessas, 869 são não-binárias.

Fazendo a conta `2,44% x 869 / 5680`, temos como resultado que 0,373% da população prisional paulista no início de 2020 era não-binária, apesar de que devido a citação dada acima, isso talvez seja subestimado.

Enfim, embora esses números não possam ser generalizados para a população como um todo e podem ser bastante imprecisos, isso mostra que provavelmente menos de 1% da população é não-binária e/ou transgênero.

## Formas de uso de linguagem neutra

> Qual percentual da população brasileira usa linguagem neutra? Se sim, que percentual é esse, e quais variações são mais comuns?

> Há uma grande interseção entre as fatias de população acima?

Isso também é algo muito difícil de avaliar quantitativamente. Mas qualitativamente, a linguagem não-binária muitas vezes diz para trocar o **o** e o **a** por **@**, **x** ou **e**. Como o stafusa mencionou na resposta dele, o número exato no final pouco importa, pois o tamanho dessa população não é justificativa para o uso ou não-uso dessa linguagem.

Além disso, há a questão de que no português, quando escrevemos algo como "**caro leitor, blablabla**", há o gênero masculino embutido aí, pois é usado "**caro leitor**" e não "**cara leitora**", sendo que pelo menos 50% da população é feminina. Então, inclusividade vai muito além das pessoas não-binárias, também temos que falar da inclusão da população feminina! Por outro lado, usar "**cara leitora**" já estaria excluindo a população masculina. Isso reforça a necessidade de existir uma linguagem neutra. Uma forma comum seria o uso de "**caro(a) leitor(a)**".

Vou discorrer sobre essas formas todas mais abaixo. A linguagem neutra não tem sido muito utilizada, frustrando as esperanças e expectativas das pessoas que a propõem. Vou explicar as razões por trás disso mais abaixo (embora eu não tenha links para nenhum estudo sólido ou quantitativo para isso).

## O uso do *@* ou do *x* no lugar de *o* e *a*

As grafias ***amig@*** ou ***amigx*** partem da ideia de que o **@** pode ser visto como uma letra **a** dentro de uma letra **o** e que o **x** vale como um caractere-coringa, podendo ser substituído por **o** ou por **a** dependendo de quem está lendo. Assim sendo, isso seria reduzido a ***amigo*** ou ***amiga***, dependendo do gênero de quem lê, evitando assumir-se ou generalizar-se o gênero masculino. Poderia igualmente ser substituído por qualquer outra letra ou símbolo que seja o desejado no caso de pessoas não-binárias.

No entanto, essas grafias são impronunciáveis, existentes apenas na forma escrita, mas não na forma falada. Nas formas plurais, ***amig@s*** e ***amigxs***, são ainda mais impronunciáveis. Isso atrapalha bastante para quem estiver utilizando um leitor de tela ou coisa similar. O mesmo vale para outras palavras assim onde a diferença entre o masculino e o feminino seja apenas o **o** e o **a**, tal como ***companheir@s*** ou ***companheirxs***, ***menin@s*** ou ***meninxs***, ***alun@*** ou ***alunx***.

Frequentemente essas palavras acompanham os advérbios ***tod@***, ***todx***, ***tod@s*** ou ***todxs***.

## O uso do *e* no lugar de *o* e *a*

Já o uso da letra *e* no lugar do *o* ou *a* deixa a palavra pronunciável e evita de atribuir, assumir ou generalizar a ela um gênero que esteja em desacordo com o de quem lê, escreve, ouve ou fala o texto, além de ser uma opção explicitamente neutra e destinada a incluir a todos, sejam do gênero masculino, feminino ou não-binário. Assim, surgem ***amigues***, ***companheires***, ***menine*** e ***alune***. Também podendo ser acompanhado de ***tode***, ***todes***, ***algume***, ***algumes*** ou ***nenhume***.

## Onde o *e* no lugar de *o* e *a* começa a falhar.

Uma vez que assim como o **@** e o **x**, o uso de **e** no lugar de **a** ou **o** se destina a corresponder com o gênero de quem lê, ouve, fala ou escreve o texto em questão, em substantivos e adjetivos que dificilmente apareceriam como denotando o público-alvo ou um grupo de pessoas que o texto escrito em linguagem inclusiva busca atingir, nunca ou quase nunca tal linguagem inclusiva é utilizada.

Vejamos, por exemplo, os termos supostamente inclusivos tais como ***marinheire***, ***conhecides***, ***vizinhes***, ***deputade***, ***catadore***, ***cachorre***, ***mexicane***, ***gregue***, ***coreane***, ***empresárie***, ***secretáries***, ***velhe***, ***tie***, ***prime***, ***sobrinhe***, ***candidates***, ***teimose***, ***irritade***, ***divertide***, ***poderoses***, ***chate***, ***caprichoses***, ***esperançose***, ***amarele*** dentre muitos outros.

Esses termos dificilmente serão entendidos como linguagem inclusiva por falantes da língua portuguesa, soando mais como:

- Erros de digitação ou de pronúncia;
- Alguma tentativa de se fazer alguma piada ou trocadilho;
- Que a palavra possa ser um verbo ao invés de um substantivo ou adjetivo;
- Que trata-se de alguma palavra emprestada do francês ou do italiano;
- Alguma outra coisa com significado bem diferente do intentado.

Pessoalmente, a primeira vez na vida que vi esses termos sendo empregados foi justamente agora quando os concebi para escrever esta resposta. As variantes que trocam o **e** por **@** ou **x** são tão ruins quanto ou piores.

A troca do **o** ou **a** por **e** em palavras onde esta vogal é precedida pela letra **c** também é problemática, pois o **c** tem som de **k** quando sucedido por **o** ou **a**, mas tem som de **s** quando sucedido por **e**. Por exemplo, ***louce*** não é a versão neutra de ***louco*** e ***louca***, enquanto que ***louque*** sofre suficiente desvio linguístico para que seu significado se torne obscuro. O mesmo acontece com ***rico*** / ***rica*** -> ***rice*** / ***rique***.

## Quando o masculino e o feminino não se limitam a *o* e *a*

Não vejo tentativa real de flexibilizar outras palavras, especialmente onde o masculino e o feminino são bastante diferentes como **ator/atriz**, **garçom/garçonete**, **pai/mãe**, **homem/mulher**, **vaca/boi**, **carneiro/ovelha** que seja incluir ambas as formas tal como em expressões como "***contrata-se garçom ou garçonete***" ou "***chame a sua mãe ou o seu pai***". Mesmo em expressões que poderiam ser flexibilizadas com **e**, **@** ou **x**, a linguagem inclusiva costuma utilizar tanto a forma feminina como a masculina, tal como "***as entrevistas com candidatos e candidatas começam amanhã***" ou "***foram colhidas assinaturas de deputados e deputadas***". No entanto, essa forma ainda estaria em tese a excluir as pessoas não-binárias.

Palavras onde a forma masculina é prefixo da feminina tradicionalmente levam o sufixo "**(a)**" na forma inclusiva, tal como em ***professor(a)***, ***lutador(a)***, ***vendedor(a)***, ***cantor(a)***. Entretanto, nos últimos anos esta forma tem sido questionada por colocar a forma feminina como secundária, levando então às formas mais verbosas e cansativas de se ler tais como ***professor ou professora***, ***lutador ou lutadora***, ***vendedor ou vendedora***, ***cantor ou cantora***. E isso ainda não resolve a questão de deixar de fora as pessoas não-binárias, o que levaria a introdução dos termos ***professore***, ***lutadore***, ***vendedore***, ***cantore*** com o complicador de que as formas plurais desses termos seriam justamente as masculinas ao invés das neutras ou não-binárias, a menos que se inventem plurais irregulares específicos para esta situação.

Palavras onde o masculino termina em **ão** também teriam suas dificuldades, tais como **anfitrião/anfitriã**, **tabelião/tabeliã**, **capitão/capitã**, **ladrão/ladra**, **grandão/grandona**, **vermelhão/vermelhona**, **irritadão/irritadona**. Não sei como seriam as versões não-binárias destas palavras, nem de seus respectivos plurais, e acho que nem nunca ouvi falar delas sequer existirem.

## Artigos, pronomes e numerais

Há algumas propostas quanto ao equivalente a ***ele***, ***ela***, ***eles*** e ***elas*** que sejam inclusivos. A saber: ***el@***, ***elx***, ***ilo***, ***el@s*, ***elxs***, ***ilos***. As formas com **@** e **x** sofrem o problema de serem impronunciáveis. Além disso, o **@** já não é mais um substituto para **a** ou **o**, e sim para **a** ou ***e*. As formas ***ilo*** e ***ilos*** são bastante obscuras e nunca vi serem usadas na prática, mesmo em textos que buscam ser inclusivos. Desconheço outras formas.

Outro problema é que a língua portuguesa tem um conjunto fechado de artigos definidos e indefinidos: **o**, **a**, **os**, **as**, **um**, **uma**, **uns** e **umas**. Tentar utilizar ***e***, ***es***, ***ume*** e ***umes*** só criará frases de sentido e significado confuso e obscuro. Ainda há a complicação introduzida pelas contrações **do**, **da**, **dos**, **das**, **no**, **na**, **nos**, **nas**, **ao**, **à**, **aos** e **às**.

Há ainda a questão de que isso não se limita aos pronomes do caso reto, mas também nos pronomes oblíquos, demonstrativos e possessivos e em contrações de pronomes. A saber: **o**, **os**, **a**, **as**, **aquele**, **aquela**, **aqueles**, **aquelas**, **dele**, **dela**, **deles**, **delas**, **daquele**, **daquela**, **daqueles**, **daquelas**, **nele**, **nela**, **neles**, **nelas**, **naquele**, **naquela**, **naqueles**, **naquelas**, **àquele**, **àquela**, **àqueles**, **àquelas**, **meu**, **minha**, **meus**, **minhas**, **teu**, **tua**, **teus**, **tuas**, **seu**, **sua**, **seus**, **suas**, **nosso**, **nossa**, **nossos**, **nossas**, **vosso**, **vossa**, **vossos**, **vossas**, **este**, **esse**, **esta**, **essa**, **estes**, **esses**, **estas**, **essas**, **deste**, **desse**, **desta**, **dessa**, **destes**, **desses**, **destas**, **dessas**, **neste**, **nesse**, **nesta**, **nessa**, **nestes**, **nesses**, **nestas** e **nessas**. Desconheço qualquer tentativa de se utilizarem pronomes possessivos e demonstrativos que sejam neutros.

Os pronomes oblíquos **lhe** e **lhes** são neutros, mas se aplicam a casos mais restritos. Já os pronomes **aquilo**, **àquilo**, **daquilo**, **naquilo**, **isso**, **isto**, **nisso**, **nisto**, **disso** e **disto** se aplicam a objetos e conceitos abstratos, e não a pessoas, além de não possuírem formas no plural.

Outro problema são os numerais. A maioria deles não variam quanto ao gênero, mas alguns variam, a saber: **um**, **uma**, **dois**, **duas**, **duzentos**, **duzentas**, **trezentos**, **trezentas**, ..., **novecentos** e **novecentas**. Novamente, desconheço quaisquer tentativas de torná-los neutros. [Veja esta outra resposta minha](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/410/57)

É claro que sempre existem substantivos e adjetivos que não variam em relação ao gênero também, tais como **motorista**, **balconista**, **atendente**, **contente**, **paranaense**, **paulista**, **canadense**, **traficante**, **eletricista**, e com eles não há muito o que se preocupar.

## Concordância nominal e verbal

As regras de concordância nominal e verbal no português são difíceis, pois elas têm gêneros que devem ser aplicadas de maneira rigorosa aos artigos, pronomes, substantivos, adjetivos, advérbios e até numerais. O gênero também influencia fortemente a gramática da linguagem, a composição de sujeitos e predicados e a relação semântica e contextual entre orações, frases e diferentes partes de um texto.

Os verbos escapam da flexão de gênero, mas as demais flexões a eles aplicadas e fortemente relacionadas também são graves complicadores ao elaborar-se frases gramaticalmente corretas.

## Reestruturação de frases

Devido a não saber como realizar a devida concordância nominal e verbal a fim de satisfazer as necessidades linguísticas de uma língua que impõe e classifica tudo exclusivamente por dois gêneros de forma um tanto ditatorial, muitas vezes a saída é reestruturar a frase de forma a evitar ter que atribuir gênero a algo que não o tem ou que tem um que não seja o masculino ou o feminino e que portanto não. Isso significa trocar **homem** e **mulher** por **pessoa**, **aluno** ou **aluna** por **estudante**, **professor** ou **professora** por **docente**...

Outra saída seria trocar algo como **leitor ou leitora** por **pessoa que lê** ou **locatário ou locatária** por **quem está alugando**.

No entanto, isso é um contorcionismo de linguagem que deveria ser desnecessário. A língua portuguesa já é suficientemente difícil e complicada. Buscar redigir um texto (ou pior ainda, manter uma conversa) de forma a tentar evitar a dificuldade de atribuir gênero a algo que tem um gênero desconhecido, não tem gênero ou tem um gênero que não se encaixa em nenhuma das duas formas que a gramática da língua portuguesa impõe de forma ditatorial chega a ser um exercício de masoquismo linguístico. Ainda mais se considerarmos que muitas vezes, o gênero do que quem quer ou do quer que seja pode ser irrelevante ao teor do texto ou da conversa não fosse o fato de isto estar imposto forçosamente dentro da própria gramática da linguagem.

## As dificuldades da linguagem inclusiva

Enfim, não sou acadêmico da área de letras ou linguística. Não li muitos artigos sobre o tema, mas o que vejo, baseado apenas na minha própria experiência empírica e anedótica, mas que garanto não ser apenas minha, é que a linguagem inclusiva tem sido ditada por causas políticas identitárias que visam impor mudanças na língua portuguesa sem considerar a complexidade e profundidade linguística que se faz necessária, vez que a língua portuguesa existe apenas com os gêneros masculinos e femininos, atribuindo e impondo-os a praticamente tudo em praticamente todos os lugares, mesmo onde seriam totalmente desnecessários, supérfluos, inúteis e/ou irrelevantes.

Demonstração disso é que as formas de trocar o **a** e o **o** por **@** ou **x** desconsideram o aspecto óbvio de que a língua não é apenas escrita, mas principalmente falada. Apenas com por isso, nem há porque entrarem-se nos méritos das implicações mais profundas acerca de concordância nominal e verbal decorrentes de tal substituição. A abordagem de trocá-los pelo **e** é um pouco mais feliz, mas ainda bastante limitada como já expliquei anteriormente.

Há ainda a questão de que nos plurais da língua portuguesa, a forma masculina predomina sobre a feminina quando os gêneros são mistos. Por exemplo, um grupo que misture alunos e alunas é referido por **eles** e por **os alunos**. A forma **elas** e **as alunas** só se aplica se não houverem participantes do sexo masculino no grupo. Isso também é considerado uma característica machista e sexista da língua portuguesa e tem sido um forte foco de discussão da pauta feminista.

Assim sendo, acredito que tentativas de se promoverem mudanças que desconsiderem toda essa complexidade, por melhores que sejam as suas motivações, nunca serão bem sucedidas por carecerem de fundamento e embasamento linguístico que possibilitem aos falantes do idioma construir frases gramaticalmente corretas.

Como exemplo, vejamos a seguinte expressão:

- *"Os duzentos deputados coreanos teimosos e loucos e o governador pediram aos dois capitães, mais verbas para eles e seus sobrinhos lutadores."*

Agora, seguem tentativas que fiz de tornar todos os termos dessa frase neutra, supondo que os deputados, o governador, os capitães e os sobrinhos sejam ou possam ser pessoas não-binárias e/ou uma mistura de homens e mulheres e não queiramos que as formas masculinas predominem na frase atribuindo o gênero masculino onde não há:

- *"Es duzentes deputades coreanes teimoses e louques e e governadore pediram ais dues capitês, mais verbas para iles e sues sobrinhes lutadorés."*
- *"Xs duzentxs deputadxs coreanxs teimosxs e loucxs e x governadorx pediram ax dxxs capitãxs, mais verbas para elxs e sxxs sobrinhxs lutadorxs."*
- *"Os/as duzento(a)s deputado(a)s coreano(a)s teimoso(a)s e louco(a)s e o/a governador(a) pediram aos dois/duas capitães(ãs), mais verbas para eles/elas e seus/suas sobrinhos(as) lutadores(as)."*
- *"Os e as duzentos ou duzentas deputados e deputadas coreanos e coreanas, teimosos e teimosas, loucos e loucas e o governador ou a governadora pediram aos dois capitães, duas capitãs ou um capitão e uma capitã, mais verbas para eles e elas e seus sobrinhos lutadores e suas sobrinhas lutadoras."*
- *"Duzentos parlamentares da Coreia com teimosia e loucura e a pessoa ocupante do cargo de governador pediram a dois militares com patente de capitão, mais verbas para si e para seus sobrinhos e sobrinhas lutadores."*

A forma com **@**, nem sei como tentar.

Você pode até argumentar de que eu não sei fazer isso direito ou de que construí um exemplo propositadamente problemático. No entanto, observe que nessa frase de exemplo, o gênero dos participantes é completamente desnecessário, supérfluo e irrelevante para exprimir a mensagem que deseja-se passar ao/à receptor(a) da mensagem. Frases com estas mesmas características são extremamente comuns em qualquer texto ou conversa em língua portuguesa. Aliás, encontrar um texto ou uma conversa em português onde o gênero de qualquer pessoa ou de qualquer coisa não interfira na escrita é que é algo quase impossível.

A própria língua portuguesa impõe a dificuldade de exigir-se que o gênero esteja presente várias e várias vezes repetidamente na maioria das palavras. Isso torna o trabalho de escrever de forma inclusiva algo bastante difícil, trabalhoso e não-natural, mas que idealmente deveria ser algo tão desnecessário e irrelevante que quem quer que esteja escrevendo ou falando nunca deveria ter motivo para ter que se preocupar com isso.

## A língua portuguesa é sexista e não é inclusiva

Enfim, sem que mudanças mais profundas sejam promovidas na língua portuguesa, isso não funciona, ao menos não ainda. A língua portuguesa atribui e impõe gênero em tudo e nela só existem dois gêneros: o masculino e o feminino. E também faz com que o masculino predomine sobre o feminino em plurais onde os gêneros são mistos. As mudanças que têm sido promovidas para tentar torná-la inclusiva e menos sexista, são apenas gambiarras linguísticas simplórias, insuficientes, superficiais e inefetivas.

Se eliminarmos da língua todas as variações de gênero, exceto onde ela seja estritamente necessária e intencional, resultaria possivelmente até em uma língua mais simples, mais fácil e mais bonita do que a língua portuguesa ao eliminar grande parte da desnecessária, supérflua e inútil complexidade ocasionada por se atribuir e se impor gênero a tudo.

Por outro lado, se essas mudanças apenas aumentarem a língua, promovendo nela três gêneros: o masculino, o feminino e o neutro ou não-binário, ou até mesmo mais variações, o resultado será uma língua ainda mais feia, mais confusa, mais complexa e mais difícil do que já é. Infelizmente, as mudanças linguísticas que têm sido propostas estão tendendo mais a este caminho.

Entretanto, o problema é que mesmo se ou quando mudanças profundas forem promovidas, o resultado será algo tão diferente da língua portuguesa que conhecemos, que de fato constituir-se-á em uma nova língua. Deixará de ser a língua portuguesa!

A língua portuguesa tradicional e uma nova língua portuguesa que seja totalmente inclusiva e igualitária seriam de fato duas línguas bem diferentes que embora viessem a ter alguma similaridade, seriam mutualmente ininteligíveis!

Assim sendo, infelizmente, temos que aceitar o fato de que **a língua portuguesa tem uma gramática inerentemente sexista e não-inclusiva e que se isso for removido e/ou consertado, ela deixará de ser a língua portuguesa e se tornará numa nova língua.**

## Outras línguas

Apesar de que para ser justo, isso não é um problema específico do português. Todas as línguas indo-europeias têm essa característica de atribuir gêneros onde não são necessários e as línguas latinas são as que têm isso de forma mais pesada, sendo que o francês é até pior do que o português neste quesito.

Curiosamente o inglês é uma das línguas indo-europeias que menos são afetadas por variações de gênero porque a Inglaterra foi habitada por povos celtas, bretões e romanos e depois foi invadida por anglos, saxões e normandos na idade média, além de ter sofrido incursão de dinamarqueses e vikings e ter se envolvido em longos períodos de guerra com a França alternados por prósperos períodos de paz com intenso contato. Isso criou várias pressões linguísticas para que a língua sofresse várias alterações, muitas delas no propósito de unificá-la, simplificá-la e uniformizá-la, o que acabou reduzindo-a gradativamente a algo que fosse o mais próximo possível de um denominador comum entendível por todos esses povos e eliminando diversas variações pronomiais e verbais que existiam no inglês antigo.

Por outro lado, o português, o espanhol, o galego e o catalão evoluíram do latim, sofrendo influências menores da língua gótica, do vandálico e do árabe, que não tiveram força o suficiente para influenciar tão pesadamente o latim dessa região, mas foi o suficiente para alterá-la de forma significativa. Além disso, o latim era a língua da igreja católica, com uma forte presença na região, diferente do que acontecia em locais de língua germânica onde apesar da influência da igreja, o latim era uma língua estrangeira falada por poucos. Assim sendo, as regras gramaticais do latim, incluindo a grande variação pronomial e verbal predominaram nessa península.

Já muitas das línguas não-indo-europeias, como o chinês e o tupi-guarani, por exemplo, para citar duas línguas bem distantes, não têm essa variação pronomial ou verbal por causa do gênero, e portanto já são neutras (apesar de que não tenho absoluta certeza disso para ser franco). Mas elas também sofrem de dificultadores e variações complexas ocasionadas por outras razões.

## Polêmica na SE

A propósito, essa abordagem de reestruturar frases para evitar atribuir um gênero quando não existe um ou quando não é claro qual é o gênero que deveria ser atribuído é algo que a ex-moderadora de diversos sites na SE, Monica Cellio realizava costumeiramente.

Por um estranho infortúnio do destino, isso acabou se transformando numa bola de neve que culminou no maior escândalo que a SE já vivenciou. Interpretaram essa atitude como se isso fosse uma forma de discriminação contra pessoas não-binárias, pois onde o gênero era claramente o masculino ou o feminino, essa reestruturação não seria necessária.

A Monica acabou sendo destituída sumariamente de forma unilateral, injusta, sem aviso prévio e sem chance de defesa. Ela não tem e nem nunca teve qualquer intenção de atacar pessoas não-binárias e a forma de escrita dela era apenas devido a aspectos puramente linguísticos. Isso levou a renúncia em massa de diversos moderadores, severo azedamento da relação da diretoria da SE com seus moderadores e usuários, saída de funcionários da empresa, e até em ao menos uma ação judicial. Para piorar, trolls e haters utilizaram o fato para atacar injustamente as pessoas não-binárias na rede.

Veja mais sobre essa polêmica [nesta pergunta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/176034) e [nesta resposta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334345/176034).

E isso aconteceu na língua inglesa, que tem muito menos problemas com gênero do que na portuguesa.

Acredito que a luta identitária é uma luta totalmente válida, mas se for levada a ferro e fogo de forma fanática, o resultado é e sempre será desastroso e fracassado. Não adianta tentar-se promover e defender causas políticas por meio de métodos simplórios, doentios ou totalitários por mais justas que sejam essas causas. Infelizmente, o diálogo sobre tornar a língua portuguesa mais inclusiva e menos sexista está longe de acabar. Quando terminar, não estaremos mais aqui e talvez nem mesmo os nossos netos, e o resultado provavelmente será muito distante do que um dia se chamou de língua portuguesa.

Comment: Belo ensaio sobre o tema. Contudo, ainda que esteja possivelmente subentendido, acho importante incluir explicitamente uma resposta direta às perguntas do OP.

Comment: @stafusa Feito, obrigado por seu comentário. Havia um outro comentário crítico aqui também que por alguma razão foi deletado, mas acho que a resposta está melhor agora e os problemas devem ter sido sanados.

Comment: Excelente explicação! Eu não esperava que adaptar a língua portuguesa a formas neutra e não-binária tivesse tantas dificuldades. Tenho de concordar com você: seria uma língua inteiramente nova. Como língua é uso, e não é imposta de cima (só regulada de cima), somente com o tempo e interesse popular a linguagem neutra vai se estabelecer. Quem sabe nos próximos séculos? Obrigado, a ambos os stafusa.